# Node js functions : sql query result call twice

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

I've got a problem with javascript/node js functions.

When I send an sql query with function query of "request.service.mssql" object, the result function is called twice...

I don't understand because my sql query is an "update" and the result is empty (I do not have multiple lines of results)

For example, I have a function that send an email with a new password. The email is sent twice... I found a temp solution with an index but it's not very clean.

**Can you explain this ?**

```
//construct SQL query
var email = "test@toto.com";
var password = require("crypto").randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
var password_md5 = require("crypto").createHash("md5").update(password).digest("hex");
var sql = "update dbo.mytable SET password='"+password_md5+"' where id=12";

var id = 0;     //temp solution

mssql.query(sql, 
{
    success: function(results) {
        //Send email with new pwd
        if(id == 0) {
            response.send(statusCodes.OK,password_md5);
            sendEmail(email,password);
        }
        id++;   //temp solution
    },
    error: function(err) {
        response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,"Error : " + err);
    }
});
```

Thank you :-)

Steve

Comment: I have strong suspicion the problem is elsewhere, because your code looks valid to me.

What if the whole code block is called twice? Please add the `console.log("IS CALLED");` as a first line here (before `var email ...`). Before digging deeper, let's get rid of the most obvious mistakes :)

Comment: It's done : "IS CALLED" appears just once.

Comment: And if I delete id=0 / id++, I get 2 mails and 1  "IS CALLED" in my logs...

Comment: Sorry Steve, I do not have any clues for you.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I will continue with my id...

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer on another forum : I have to prefix my SQL statement with `set nocount on;` command.

Thank you for your help.

Steve